# when is a ring a free module over a subring?

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, modules, big-list

Let $S \subset R$ be rings, $S$ not necessarily an ideal of $R$, and $S \neq R$.

Is there anything that can be said about when $R$ is free as an $S$-module?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one situation in which $R$ can be free over $S$ (I only deal with Noetherian local rings here):

If $S$ is a regular local ring, and $R$ is a finite $S$-module, then $R$ is a free $S$-module iff $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring. This follows from the [Auslander-Buchsbaum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslander%E2%80%93Buchsbaum_formula). If $R$ is complete and contains a field, then there does exist a regular subring $S \subseteq R$ such that $R$ is a finite $S$-module.

Comment: Ah! Does the Cohen-Macaulay situation generalize the one I tried with the PID? I don't know anything about Cohen-Macaulay rings so I don't know how they would relate to torsion.

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes, it is a direct generalization. As I'm sure you know, PIDs are locally DVRs which are precisely the 1-dim regular local rings, and also in this (1-dim) case, the Cohen-Macaulay condition reduces exactly to torsion-freeness. Moreover free is equivalent to locally free over PIDs. I hadn't thought about it that way before though - the statement for PIDs is a direct consequence of the structure theorem - so thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: That teaches me something as well too: thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there are many spectacular answers, but here are some obvious ones.

When S is a division ring, this is the case.

When R is a flat extension of S and S is a local perfect ring.

When R is a projective extension of S and S is a local ring.

When S is a commutative principal ideal domain and R is finitely generated and torsionfree over S.